# Entropy theorem $S(\rho)>\theta S(\rho_1)+(1-\theta)S(\rho_2)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Considering the definition of entropy:
$$S(\rho)=-k_b Tr(\rho\log\rho)$$
Let the statistical mixture of states:
$$\rho=\theta \rho_1+(1-\theta)\rho_2$$
I know the following theorem is valid:
$$S(\rho)>\theta S(\rho_1)+(1-\theta)S(\rho_2)$$
I am looking for the  simplest demonstration of that theorem. I'm not looking for the most general demonstration possible, because my mathematical skills are not very solid.
Online I can not find anything that is what I'm looking for. If you can even just write a link, you would do me a big favor.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a simple example, take $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ to be pure states, e.g.
$$ \rho_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} , \qquad
   \rho_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} . $$
Then $S(\rho_1) = S(\rho_2) = 0$ and
$$ S(\rho) = -\theta \log \theta - (1-\theta) \log (1-\theta) \geq 0. $$
(Exercise: Show that $-x \log x \geq 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Actually I'm not looking for a specific example but a more general demonstration. $ \forall \rho_1,\rho_2,\theta$.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you are looking for. Either you are looking for a *proof* for all $\rho_i, \theta$ or for an example. If it is the former, 10 seconds of google search yield this https://bit.ly/2ozkang (page 6). I don't think you will find an "easier" proof.